# DirectorySearch.Findone() is not working when deploying in server?

Tags: c#

I am using DirectorySearch.FindOne() under Hosting Environment class to retrieve user details from Active Directory. It is working fine in localhost but when I put it on the server its throwing an error.

Even in IIS I have changed my ApplicationPoolIdentity to Network service then also no use.

Do I need to add something else to web.config to make it work. The following is my code.

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        strrUser = txtUserName.Text;
        strPassword = txtPWD.Text;
        role = txtRole.SelectedItem.Value;

        //string selectedrole = txtRole.SelectedValue;
        using (PrincipalContext pContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
        {
            if (pContext.ValidateCredentials(strrUser, strPassword))
            {
                SearchResult result;
                using (HostingEnvironment.Impersonate())
                {
                    DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher();
                    ds.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
                    ds.ReferralChasing = ReferralChasingOption.All;
                    ds.Filter = String.Format("(&(objectCategory=person)(sAMAccountName={0}))", strrUser);

                    result = ds.FindOne();

                }
                if (result != null)
                {
                    DirectoryEntry entry = result.GetDirectoryEntry();
                    employeeID = entry.Properties["physicaldeliveryofficename"].Value.ToString();
                    username = entry.Properties["displayName"].Value.ToString();
                }
```

Comment: `in server its throwing the error` what is the error?

Comment: Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted.

Comment: Above is the error i am getting..but according to my knowledge it tries to access same somain which I want. Also, the same set of coding is successully working for another application which is hosted in same server in another port. But I dont think its a port issue as login page, then primary credential validations using principal context class ae working good, but not findone()

Answer (score 0):

Do not run code under Network Service credentials. Create a custom user, that can search the AD, and either run the pool with that user, or impersonate it to run the code.

The reason this works on localhost is because you usually use your own user to test this... another reason is that maybe you are not searching the domain you think you're...

anyways, you should post the error...

Comment: Hi Leonardo, Thanks for your quick reply. Even I tried using custom account(both Server credentials and administrator credentials). Also, I am sure it is trying to access correct domain only, since before the error happens it successfully checks for username and password and the error happens when tries to retrieve the user details using findone(). Also, in my webconfig anything can be done to make it work?..because aleady i tried using <identity impersonate="false" /> and <identity impersonate="true" /> as well.

Comment: Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted.   I am stuck up with this single error for past three four days. pls help..

Comment: It is perfectly validating credentials in the same domain, but fails to retrieve the credential details..

Comment: Try using the overload where you explicitly set the domain you're searching